# Is is possible to have a HTTP wordpress installation behind an HTTPS reverse proxy? (mixed content message)

Tags: wordpress, nginx, reverse-proxy

I have ServerA running an NGINX reverse proxy.

It is point towards ServerB.

Server B is http://1.1.1.1 for argument.

I'm getting the homepage served however all of the CSS/IMAGE etc etc links are all pointed towards http://1.1.1.1/wp-content etc etc

So I'm getting blocked message because they are being served via HTTP and not HTTPS.

Is there a way around this? Someway to have all of the links to content be relative and just dealt with from the proxy?

Comment: The URL used by a WordPress site for resource files (CSS, JS, IMG) can be configured on the [Settings -> General screen](https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/changing-the-site-url/). Either set the correct value or remove the `http://1.1.1.1` part to make it relative.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is just to set the **WordPress Address (URL)** and **Site Address (URL)** fields in *Settings* > *General* to the hostname of ServerA, as suggested by Richard.

But keep ind mind that you can't set those 2 fields to a relative URL as [WordPress uses absolute URLs by design](https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/contribute/design-decisions/#absolute-versus-relative-urls).

Making this change also auto-redirects to the hostname of ServerA if you access it without going through the reverse-proxy.